# How to checkout remote svn branch locally?

Tags: svn

I have installed svn on my local ubuntu. I'm connected to my Solaris box via VPN so I can access it via a local network IP. How can I checkout a branch from the svn on solaris to get it into my local svn?

I tried:

```
svn checkout file:///192.168.99.3/home/myproj/apps/repo/sjl
```

but is says: svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL

I have also tried:

```
svn checkout svn://192.168.99.3/home/myproj/apps/repo/sjl
svn: Can't connect to host '192.168.99.3': Connection refused
```

Why refused? The ping to 192.168.99.3 works just fine.

Comment: Do you get any error? Try using this svn checkout file:///192.168.99.3/home/myproj/apps/repo/sjl ~

Comment: Sorry, a copy and paster error. It says svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL

Comment: Is the Solaris box running an svn server?

Comment: @gbarry not sure. how do I figure that out?

Comment: Try the svn+ssh access method using the URL: svn+ssh://<username>@192.168.99.3/home/myproj/apps/repo/sjl, where <username> is your username on the remote machine. See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion

Comment: Well, you would have installed it :)  Also, you can do the same telnet trick I described below, right on the server.  You can use localhost in place of the address (either should work).  If you are used to using file:/// all the time then you probably didn't set up a server.

Comment: N.B. if you are the only user or all users also have access to the server, you are fine with svn over SSH. If you want a more sophisticated system look into either WebDAV (over HTTP) or SVN serve. Both are explained in the Ubuntu community wiki to which I linked.

Comment: @Legolas It says: bash: svn+ssh://root@192.168.99.3/home/myproj/apps/repo/sjl: No such file or directory Not sure Why... I did pwd on the Solaris box and I got: /home/supl/apps/repo/sjl

Comment: @Thomas you did `svn checkout svn+ssh://root@192.168.99.3/home/myproj/apps/repo/sjl`? As the error seems like the command was wrong and not the URL.

Comment: @Legolas You're right. I did try again and now it says: bash: svnserve: command not found
svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly

Comment: @Thomas this points at missing software. Is subversion properly installed on both machines?

Comment: On the Solaris 100% yes, because it has been used for a long time. Not sure how to check it locally.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install subversion` on Ubuntu

Comment: well, that's what I did this morningme@ubuntu:~/.subversion$ sudo apt-get install subversion
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
subversion is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.

Comment: On Solaris: -bash-3.00# /opt/csw/bin/svn --version
svn, version 1.6.2 (r37639) compiled Jun 13 2009, 21:42:49
The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_neon : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using Neon.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try replacing `file:///` with `svn://`.

`file` should only work if your repository is one the same machine as you.  `svn:` is the "real" over-the-network protocol.

`svn:` is appropriate if your Solaris box is an svn server.  But the path to the repository should be determined by the server.  Something a lot closer to `svn://192.168.99.3/sjl`.

Comment: I tried but it say svn checkout svn://192.168.99.3/home/myproj/apps/repo/sjl
svn: Can't connect to host '192.168.99.3': Connection refused

Comment: Okay, try changing the path, like I added to my answer.  It's a lot like how a web server points to a directory and you don't specify the path that leads to it.

Comment: @gbarry: the connection refused part probably points at no SVN server, or does it also give this error when accessing the wrong URL?

Comment: First you have to get a connection before you worry about finding the right path to the repo.  A wrong URL should give a different message.  Per legolas you might want to see that you can log into that box in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another trick, because ping doesn't guarantee you can make a connection.

```
telnet 192.168.99.3 3690
```

If you connect successfully to the svn server (3690 is its port number by default), you'll get a response that looks something like this:

> ( success ( 1 2 ( ANONYMOUS ) ( edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries
>   ) ) )

hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it will close the connection.  But if, instead, you get a connection error message, then you need to look at your network or firewall.

Comment: This doesn't work.telnet 192.168.99.3 3690
Trying 192.168.99.3...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that was solved by allowing port 3690 in my firewall:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 3690 -j ACCEPT
```

I tried gbarry's command `telnet my.ip 3690`, and since I had no responde (although `ping my.ip` worked) I knew it was a firewall problem.

Answer (score -5):

1. Identify, which access methods you have enabled and configured on repo-side (SVN-repository can be reached remotely with svn:// svn+ssh:// http:// protocols)
2. Define full URL of repo (server-dependent)
3. Use it

You can go through the options blindly and unthinkingly for a very long time. Use brain!

You may have only local file:/// access-method in your Ubuntu

**READ DOCS!**